# Including a url link for App Store review before submit causes reject?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Apple App Store review guideline says all url link in the app should be alive when submit app for review.
But the app review link included in my app can't be alive before passing review, right?
Should I remove 'Please review this app' button when submit for the first review and update as soon as my app's on sale in App Store?
Anybody has experience related this issue?
Maybe Apple make an exception for the review link only?

PS. I'm not asking how to get the review link before submit. I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not cause rejection. The reason is review team already knows that Apps iTunes link will not be active until app is live.

Another most important thing is review team can view the link which we have used for app review & confirm that we have passed valid APP Id into the link. So that confirms that it will start working once App is live.

Hope it will help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted all my version 1.0 apps with an App Store URL review link and have never been rejected. However my last version 1.0 was submitted November 2015. Review times are very quick at time of writing, if they reject it for that reason just remove it and re submit it.